# rbindlist for factors with missing levels

Tags: r, data.table

I have several `data.tables` that I would like to `rbindlist`. The tables contain factors with (possibly missing) levels. Then `rbindlist(...)` behaves differently from `do.call(rbind(...))`:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x=factor(c("a", "b"), levels=letters))

rbindlist(list(dt1, dt1))[,x] 
## [1] a b a b
## Levels: a b

do.call(rbind, list(dt1, dt1))[,x]
## [1] a b a b
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

If I want to keep the levels, do I have tor resort to `rbind` or is there a `data.table` way?

Comment: You can always grab the levels before you call `rbindlist` and then put em back (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634964/how-does-one-change-the-levels-of-a-factor-column-in-a-data-table)).  But I think you're right there should be a `droplevels=TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `rbindlist` is faster because it  doesn't do the checking of `do.call(rbind.data.frame,...)`

Why not to set the levels after binding?

```
    Dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt1)) 
    setattr(Dt$x,"levels",letters)  ## set attribute without a copy
```

from the `?setattr`:

> setattr() is useful in many situations to set attributes by reference and can be used on any object or part of an object, not just data.tables.

Comment: Thanks. But where I actually use this, I do not know the levels. If I have 2 `data.tables`, I already need `unique(unlist(lapply(list(dt1, dt2), function(dt) levels(dt[,x]))))` to find the levels, and I am afraid then the `do.call(rbind, ...)` version may be faster.

Comment: @shadow I'm guessing that'll only be slower if you have a very large number of rows with an even larger number of factor levels, in which case I'd ask - what's the point of having factors? I'd only use factors if I had a small number of elements that are used over and over again in the data with a large degree of repetition

Comment: fwiw, if you use the internal `c.factor` function you can speed that last step up quite a bit: `do.call(data.table:::c.factor, lapply(list(dt1, dt2), "[[", 'x'))` in your scenario

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out this problem. As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?root=datatable&view=log) it has been fixed:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x=factor(c("a", "b"), levels=letters))

rbindlist(list(dt1, dt1))[,x]
#[1] a b a b
#Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```