# Change factor levels in data.tables by name

Tags: r, data.table, r-factor

I understand how I can change a column's levels when I explicitly define the column name like in this example from Matt Dowle :

```
setattr(mydt$value,"levels",c(...))
```

Though, in real-life problems, you often don't know the column names. This technique does not seem to work when "value" is not explicitly given in the code :

```
setattr(mydt[,get("value")],"levels",c(...))
```

And that is a problem. I guess this syntax gives me the column by copy and not a reference to the column, contrary to mydt$value, but I don't know how to fix this :'(

Thanks

Please see [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634964/how-does-one-change-the-levels-of-a-factor-column-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work:

```
setattr(mydt[["value"]],"levels",c(...))
```

Comment: Great. That is exactly what I was looking for.