# Manually Ordering and Renaming Geom_Bar Stacked Bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to find a solution to my issue below; all help would be appreciated.

I conducted clustering and extracted assigned 'cluster' assignments k = 1-3.

However, the numeric label attached to the cluster assignment does not reflect an ordered value, and I'd like to create a barplot with cluster labels corresponding to the order of X.

As it stands, the cluster output generates: Cluster A = 1, Cluster B = 3, and Cluster C = 2.

I'd like to order the barplots but given the problem above, is there a way to control the breaks such that 1,3,2 represents A,B,C?

All help would be appreciated.

```
#LIBRARIES

library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

#MOCK DATA

X <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

Cluster <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

DAT %>% mutate(Cluster = case_when(X < 2 ~ "1",
                                   X <4 ~ "3",
                                   X <6 ~ "2"))
X <- as.factor(X)
DAT <- data.frame(X, Cluster)

#EXISTING CODE ATTEMPT

ggplot(DAT, aes(x= Cluster, fill = X), color = "X") +
geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat="count", width = 0.80) +
theme_ipsum(axis = TRUE, grid = FALSE, axis_col = "black", base_size = 9) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 9, face = "bold"),
axis.text = element_text(size = 9)) +
scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "G")+
  (scale_x_reverse(breaks = c(1:3), labels = paste("Cluster", LETTERS[1:3])))+
   coord_flip() +
  xlab("")
```

This is my desired visual with the X fill changed to account for cluster order.

[image: This is the desired visual. With the X fill changed]

Comment: Try with `scale_x_reverse(breaks = c(1:3), labels = paste0("X-Cluster ", 1:3))`

Comment: Hi @stefan. I made a content change to provide more clarity. Thanks for your help. I hadn't made myself clear enough, originally

Comment: You can manually set the factor levels. The forcats package makes this very easy

Comment: Thanks @camille. I'll check it out. If you have an example too, that would be very helpful

Comment: I think this is most likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52171943/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33538059/5325862, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7150453/5325862, among others. Those should help you out with examples

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, manually set the factor levels.

```
X <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

Cluster <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE)

DAT <- data.frame(X, Cluster)

DAT <- DAT %>% dplyr::mutate(Cluster = case_when(X < 2 ~ "1",
                                   X <4 ~ "3",
                                   X <6 ~ "2"))
# X <- as.factor(X)

DAT$Cluster <- factor(DAT$Cluster, levels = c("3","2","1") ) ###  manually set the factor levels


ggplot(DAT, aes(x= Cluster, fill = as.factor(X)), color = "X") +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat="count", width = 0.80) +
  theme_ipsum(axis = TRUE, grid = FALSE, axis_col = "black", base_size = 9) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 9, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "G") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = as.character(1:3), labels = paste("Cluster", LETTERS[1:3])) +  ###  display Cluster A, Cluster B, Cluster C
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("")
```